# Short "if" statement without "else"

Tags: c#, if-statement, linq-to-entities

I have a class:

```
public class DriverShortInfoElement
{
    ......
    public DateTime? VistracksDateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to fill it by data from DbContext. I want to fill VistracksDateAdded only some condition is true, otherwise leave as null:

I try such way:

```
var list = (from i in _db.Drivers
            select new DriverShortInfoElement()
            {
                .....
                VistracksDateAdded = (i.ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver != null) ? i.ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver.DateAdded : null
            }).ToList();
```

but compilation error. How to do it this simple thing?

Comment: Can you post the error please?

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You can use [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/).

Comment: First one makes no sense, since you're applying `??` to `bool`, which is not nullable. Second one probably needs need a cast to `DateTime?`.

Comment: You're using `??` wrong.

Comment: The MCVE for the second one would be `int? i = true ? 1 : null;`

Comment: You might be able to use Linq DefaultIfEmpty method to provide a Null object if the sequence is empty. If its not empty you can use Select to new up a more useful object. It might clean up your code a little. Ternary operators - essentially if-else is quite ugly.

Comment: @IanRobertson why if-else is uglier, than LinqDefaultIfEmpty with subquery? :)

Comment: You might be able to do something like: _db.Drivers.DefaultIfEmpty(new NullObject()).Select(d => new UsefulObject(d)).Where(d => some_condition)

Comment: @IanRobertson, my opinion, this code is much more ugly and unclear, that if-else statement

Comment: Up to you of course. Reducing if-else is not a bad goal. Reduces cyclomatic complexity, and can make testing easier. Also, removing if-else and ternary operators reduces branching in your flow - can make the cognitive load less - improving maintainability, reducing the time for someone else to understand your code. I was merely giving you an option you may not have thought of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `DateAdded` is a `DateTime`. If you use the conditional operator you either have to cast the `null` to `DateTime?` or use `new Nullable<DateTime>()` because there is no implicit conversion possible between `null` and `DateTime`:

```
VistracksDateAdded = i.ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver != null
    ? i.ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver.DateAdded 
    : new Nullable<DateTime>()
```

Comment: What is the different with second example ?

Comment: @Stormcloak: he uses `null` but the conditional operator doesn't allow this because the is no implicit conversion between datetime and null. He could use it if it was an `if...else`

Comment: `default(DateTime?)`

Comment: @Stormcloak It uses the `DateTime?` type for the `null`. `?:` works if one side is `DateTime` and the other `DateTime?` but not when one is `DateTime` and the other `null`.

Answer (score 3):

there is another operator: [Null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

```
VistracksDateAdded = i.ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver?.DateAdded
```

Comment: Linq to Entities does not allow null propagating operator

Comment: really? why? I cannot find any samples

Comment: Compilator says: 
Error CS8072 An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator.

Answer (score -1):

```
var query =
    from driver in _db.Drivers
    select new DriverShortInfoElement
    {
        VistracksDateAdded = driver.ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver != null
            ? driver.ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver.DateAdded
            : default(DateTime?)
    };
```